# Search with wildcard in a Collection of String

Tags: java, collections, wildcard

I have a `HashMap<Integer,String>`. I tried the following code to query the Map and return all possible values

```
public Collection<String> query(String queryStr) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        if (queryStr.matches(entry.getKey()))
            list.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    if (list.isEmpty())
        return null;
    else
        return list;
}
```

If map has `"test","best","crest","zest","testy","tether","temper","teat","tempest"`.  A query of `te*t` should return `"teat","tempest","test"`. For 'test*' it should return "test", "testy". How to implement it? Is there any wildcard search for string? And I can't use any external libraries.

Comment: `String` has the method `matches`. You can also use `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes.

Comment: Why return null if the list is empty? It would make more sense to just return an empty list.

Comment: A test of assertArrayEquals(new Object[] {"best","crest","tempest","test","zest"}, getSortedArray(dict.query("*est"))); is not returning anything.

Comment: @arshajii Its the requirement of the test cases. I cannot change them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String queryStr="te*t";

queryStr = queryStr.replaceAll("\\*", "\\\\w*");

System.out.println(query(queryStr));
```

The Complete program

```
public class sample {

    static List<String> values = Arrays.asList("test","best","crest","zest","testy","tether","temper","teat","tempest");

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String queryStr = "te*t";
        queryStr = queryStr.replaceAll("\\*", "\\\\w*");
        System.out.println(queryStr);
        System.out.println(query(queryStr));

    }

    public static Collection<String> query(String queryStr) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String str : values) {
            if (str.matches(queryStr))
                list.add(str);
        }
        if (list.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The matcher `\w*` searches for the following chars only : `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`
If you would like to search for all the chars using the `*` matcher then you should try this:

```
queryStr = queryStr.replaceAll("\\*", ".*");
```